# let the user sort with selectboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a unknown select-boxes as I use to let the user to be able to sort rows saved in a table. In this example I let the user sort his favorite color:

https://jsfiddle.net/rutnceL7/2/

```
Orange
<select name="nr[]" onchange="sortselect(this.id);">
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>Green
<select name="nr[]" onchange="sortselect(this.id);">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select><br>Blue
<select name="nr[]" onchange="sortselect(this.id);">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" selected>3</option>
</select><br>
```

Is it possible to use pure Javascript (or Jquery,but I prefer Javascript) to make this happen:
- The user takes green (2. place) and change it to first place.
- Then the javascript should find where the first place is and change that one to second place (because green was 2. before)

So in a way it switches the number the user choose. Is this possible in a simple way?

I have tried to search on google (and stackoverflow), but have not found anything. I dont like you to do the programming, but I dont know where to start.

Comment: I don't think that multiple select boxes is the right UX for ordering a list of items.  Check [Sortable](https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close! What you are talking about is DOM manipulation, and is essentially what javascript was built for.

First, you aren't setting any ids on your elements, in order to query by id you gotta have those. This is as simple as setting `<select id='foo'>`

Each select id should be unique so you can reference in your script.

Next, you'll need to modify the DOM onchange, which you aleady have set up - but you're not performing the actual modification. You'll need to add and remove elements from the DOM. You can use `element.appendChild(child)` where 'element' is the target to append to and 'child' is the element you want to add. You should read through the MDN reference to get a better understanding (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). `.removeChild()` and `.replaceChild()` work in a similar fashion and may be of interest to you.

One caveat, you will need to use actual html elements as the 'child' in many of the functions above. This means you'll need to identify the element that the user has selected and reorder based on that. It might be easier to set the values to an array in order `['Orange', 'Green', 'Blue']`, and perform the logic to reorder the array on change, and then re-render based on the state of the array.

Conceptually it sounds complex, but its actually easier than you might think. Good luck :)